# Android CMake "fatal error: 'bits/libc-header-start.h' file not found"

Tags: android, c++, cmake

I met this problem in android studio. I am going to make native c code that is used in android project. I use cmake. In order to curl some url I include some libraries to CMakeLists.txt. Following is my CMakeLists.txt file content.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY BOTH)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE BOTH)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE BOTH)

set(CURL_INCLUDE_DIR "/usr/include")
set(CURL_LIBRARY "-lcurl")

find_package(CURL REQUIRED)
include_directories(${CURL_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_library(native-lib SHARED native-lib.cpp )

find_library(log-lib log )

target_link_libraries(native-lib ${CURL_LIBRARIES} ${log-lib})
```

And then I met following fatal error.

> /usr/include/stdint.h:26:10: fatal error: 'bits/libc-header-start.h' file not found
>    #include `<bits/libc-header-start.h>`
>   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Can anybody help me? Please...

Comment: Using `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_*` suggests that you are **cross-compiling**. And system include directory `/usr/include` is rarely useful for cross-compiling. You need to use `curl` library which is built for target platform, not for the host one.

Comment: Thanks for your response. By the way, instead of using <CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_*>, I should use curl c library that is proper for my target platform, you meant? I wonder if you mention where I can find and include that library. Would you like to help me?

Comment: As I said, you need `curl` library suited for the target platform. I don't know where to obtain it.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably, improperly impossible to cross-compile curl library that is suit for all types of devices. I found three types of library: `armeabi`, `armeabi-v7a` and `x86`. However 64-bit architecture cpu can execute 32-bit programs automatically under the adaptive function of operating system. These three libraries are found in commonly cocos2d-x game-source-project. So this article reader should use ndk-build instead of cmake to reach this condition, suit-target-device.